# Form alter + Unlimited Values + Entity Reference Field

Tags: forms, ajax

- There are two fields, News Type (Selectbox),  News (Reference Entities, Unlimited option, autocomplete)
- When user select a news type, options of News fields needs to revised.
- Example: Selecting World needs to display the News related to World.
- I have added the ajax callback to get the revised data
- I received the options
- But when i submit the form or click on add more it says "This entity (node: 6) cannot be referenced. "

```
function featured_news_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_featured_news']['#prefix'] = '<div id="news-wrapper">';
  $form['field_featured_news']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  $form['field_news_type']['widget']['#ajax'] = [
    'callback' => 'updateNews',
    'disable-refocus' => FALSE,
    'event' => 'change',
    'wrapper' => 'news-wrapper',
    'progress' => [
      'type' => 'throbber',
      'message' => t('Loading...'),
    ],
  ];

  if (!empty($values) && !empty($values['field_news_type'])) {
    $type = $form_state->getValue('field_news_type')[0]['value'];
    foreach ($form_state->getValue('field_featured_news') as $key => $value) {
      $form['field_featured_news']['widget'][$key]['target_id']['#selection_settings']['view']['arguments'][0] = $type;
    }
  }
}

function updateNews(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  return $form['field_featured_news'];
}
```